# Graph Coloring based on neighboring vertices? Cellular Automata

Tags: graphs-and-networks, automation, cellular-automata

I would like to apply a majority rule cellular automata to graphs. Specifically, I would like to take a graph as input, and then define two functions, InitialColoring[graph] and MajorityRule[graph]. Suppose the set of colors is some given finite list.

InitialColoring[graph] uses some rule (such as randomly assigning colors to each vertex).
MajorityRule[graph] this "updates" the coloring for a given graph by getting the neighbors of each vertex, checking which color has the majority, and then coloring the majority color. For simplicity, let's assume the set of colors only has two colors, and if there is a tie, the vertex keeps its current color.

My thoughts:
Make a loop ranging over vertices, get neighbors, get colors, count colors, apply. I am very new to Mathematica so I am not sure how to implement this. Any suggestions on this approach or a better method to accomplish the same goal?

Also note: I want to apply cellular automata to graphs (specifically CayleyGraphs), not just the integer lattice so the built-in CellularAutomata function doesn't seem to help much.

**EDIT: EXAMPLE:**

Suppose we have the graph shown in the upper left corner in the figure below.

[image: Sample Automata]
We want to apply the rule that a vertex's color is determined by the color of the majority of its neighbors (if there is a tie, it keeps its color). Below shows an example of the progression of this automata. This outlines what I want:
1) enter a graph with an initial coloring
2) apply a rule (shown through progression of arrows) that outputs a new graph (or perhaps two functions, one that outputs the graph data, and one that outputs the color data... then these are combined in some way... I'm not sure which would be easier/more efficient to implement).

I am lost as to how to implement this, although the algorithm is pretty easy. In fact, focusing to the case where we only have two colors and the majority rule would suffice.

**EDIT 2: Further Details**
Updating should be synchronous, i.e., when we go from one time to the next, it should look like we updated every vertex all at once. Otherwise, we could get unwanted colorings due to intermediate updates in sequential updating. For example, in the example above, if we colored the top vertex first, and then proceeded, the rightmost vertex would stay blue the next generation instead of changing to red.

Also, when checking for the vertex's color, the vertex itself should only be considered in the event of a tie, i.e., it is not considered one of its neighbors unless there is a loop (we don't assume graphs are implicitly reflexive).

Comment: Would you please try to add a concrete example of what you describe?

Comment: There is closely related demonstration: [Four-Color Outer Median Cellular Automata on Graphs](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FourColorOuterMedianCellularAutomataOnGraphs/)

Comment: Shouldn't the update stop at step 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More is better, other variation:

```
upDateColor[g_] :=
 Block[{color, vlist, c},
  color = Association[PropertyValue[g, VertexStyle]];
  vlist = VertexList[g];
  SetProperty[g, 
   VertexStyle -> 
    Table[v -> 
      If[Length[c = Commonest[color /@ AdjacencyList[g, v]]] == 1, 
       First[c], color[v]], {v, vlist}]]
  ]
```

example:

```
g = PetersenGraph[5, 
   2, {VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 200, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
    VertexStyle -> 
     Thread[Range[10] -> RandomChoice[{Red, Blue, Green}, {10}]]}];

Row@Most[FixedPointList[upDateColor, g]]
```

[image]

in case of repeating sequence, you could define a function like below to detect sequence pattern (this one only detect result one above):

```
iFixedPointList[func_, g_, n___] :=
 Block[{i},
  i = g;
  FixedPointList[func, g, n, 
   SameTest -> (SameQ[i, #2] || (i = #1; SameQ[#1, #2]) &)]
  ]

SeedRandom[1]; g = 
 PetersenGraph[5, 
  2, {VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 200, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
   VertexStyle -> 
    Thread[Range[10] -> RandomChoice[{Red, Blue}, {10}]]}];

iFixedPointList[upDateColor, g] // Length
```

> 4

```
FixedPointList[upDateColor, g, 6] // Length
```

> 7

Comment: Could you provide more information on how to use this...?

Comment: @user2154420 just same as others.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to halt? I ran it, changing {Red, Blue, Green} to {Red, Blue}, and there hasn't been any output... still calculating away.

Comment: @user2154420 I didn't think of that... but you're correct I don't have any theoretical background that guarantee the convergence (seems not). Just add 3rd argument to FixedPointList to prevent infinite computations...

Comment: This works really well! Do you know of any way to make it automatically stop if it reaches a period two, i.e., the graph coloring is equivalent to the one two places before it. I'm still looking into the FixedPointList documentation for this...

Comment: @user2154420 I added function that could do what you want.

Comment: Great! Just out of curiosity what do the #1, #2, and & at the end of the or statement do?

Comment: @user2154420 you could get those information by checking documentation : Slot (#) and Function (&)

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** The original post below computes the commonest color in the `NeighborhoodGraph` of a  vertex `v` including the vertex `v` itself. To exclude a vertex in counting the colors in its neighborhood, we can use the following helper function:

```
ClearAll[newClrF];
newClrF = Module[{nc=#, oc=First@#, c1= Commonest[Rest@#][[1]], c2= Quiet@Commonest[Rest@#, 2]}, 
            If[And[Length@c2 > 1, Equal @@ (Count[Rest@nc, #] & /@ c2)], oc, c1]] &;
```

and modify `reColorF1` and `reColorF2`:

```
ClearAll[reColorF1B, reColorF2B];
reColorF1B = Module[{g = #1, vl = VertexList[#1], cl, ncl},
    ncl = (neighborColorsF[g, #1] &) /@ vl; cl = newClrF /@ ncl;                      
    MapThread[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexStyle] = #2) &, {vl, cl}]; g] &;

reColorF2B = Module[{g = #1, vl = VertexList[#1], cl, ncl},
    ncl = (neighborColorsF[g, #1] &) /@ vl; cl = newClrF /@ ncl;                              
    SetProperty[g, VertexStyle -> Thread[vl -> cl]]] &;
```

Using the same examples as in the previous post:

```
Grid[Most@FixedPointList[reColorF1B, #, 5] & /@ {g1, g2}]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
g3 = SetProperty[g, {VertexStyle -> 
     Thread[Range[10] -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Red, Green, Orange, Red, Red, Orange}], 
        VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 100}];
Grid[Most@FixedPointList[#, g3, 9] & /@ {reColorF1, reColorF1B}]
```

[image]

---

**Previous post:** In the following, color counts in the neighborhood of a vertex `v` include the color of vertex `v`.

```
ClearAll[neighborsF, neighborColorsF, commonestColorF, reColorF1, reColorF2];
neighborsF = Function[{g, v}, VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, v]]];
neighborColorsF = Function[{g, v}, PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexStyle] & /@ neighborsF[g, v]];
commonestColorF = Function[{g, vl}, (Commonest[neighborColorsF[g, #]][[1]]) & /@ vl];
```

Using the above helper functions, define

```
reColorF1 =  Module[{g = #, vl = VertexList @ #, cl = commonestColorF[#, VertexList @ #]}, 
             MapThread[(PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexStyle] = #2) &, {vl, cl}]; g] &;
```

Alternatively, you can use `SetProperty` to change the vertex colors:

```
reColorF2 =  Module[{g = #, vl = VertexList @ #, cl = commonestColorF[#, VertexList @ #]}, 
             SetProperty[g, VertexStyle -> Thread[vl -> cl]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
g = PetersenGraph[5, 2];
g1 = SetProperty[g, { VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 200, 
       VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
       VertexStyle -> Thread[Range[10] -> RandomChoice[{Red, Blue, Green}, {10}]]}];
g2 = SetProperty[g, { VertexSize -> Large, ImageSize -> 200, 
       VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
       VertexStyle -> Thread[Range[10] -> RandomChoice[{Red, Blue, Green}, {10}]]}];

Grid[Most@FixedPointList[reColorF1, #, 5] & /@ {g1, g2}]
```

[image]

```
Grid[Most@FixedPointList[reColorF2, #, 5] & /@ {g1, g2}]
(* same picture *)
```

**Note:** Breaking ties in favor of current color:

OP's requirement

> "if there is a tie, the vertex keeps its current color"

is satisfied, i.e., both functions above break ties in favor of the current own color, because

1. `VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g, x]]` lists `x` as the first vertex, and
2. `Commonest[list]` breaks the ties based on the order the elements appear in `list`.

Comment: Very nice, +1, but is this "if there is a tie, the vertex keeps its current color" satisfied? Don't you just choose 1st color in the list of ties?

Comment: @Vitaly, you are right, thank you. Will update with a fix for the tie-breaking problem.

Comment: @Vitaly, come to think of it, we don't need a fix. The function `recolorF` breaks ties in favor of the current own color because (1) `VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[g1, v]]` lists `v` as the first vertex and (2) `Commonest[list]` breaks the ties based on the order the elements appear in `list`.

Comment: Did you assume sequential updating instead of updating everything at once? The leftmost blue vertex in the first generation should turn green in the next since the majority of its neighbors are green.

Comment: for g1, lower left red should turn green?

Comment: All of this minutia about tie-breaking doesn't seem to address the very real possibility that a vertex could have 10 red neighbors, 10 blue neighbors, no other neighbors, but be green.

Comment: user2154420 & @halmir, the difference is due the fact that a vertex `v` is not excluded when computing the commonest color in its neighborhood. Please see the update.

Comment: @user2154420, updating _is_ "synchronous" in both versions.

Comment: @KellenMyers Yes, I realized that when I posted the problem. I only consider two colorings so should've made the question more specific. Also, when I run the program it runs great, but sometimes it outputs two rows of petersen graphs, who seem very unrelated. In fact, it outputted one row whose last graph was all red, and then a second row (perhaps starting over?) whose last graph was all blue. Is there any way to make it so there is just one row of evolutions from a single initial configuration, or implement a slider-like program like in the other answer. 
EDIT: Commonest won't work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

First, let's whip up a random graph:

```
n = RandomInteger[{10, 15}];
m = RandomInteger[{Floor[n^2/20], n (n - 1)/2}];
G = RandomGraph[{n, m}];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  chi[0, i] = {Red, Blue}[[RandomInteger[] + 1]]
  ];
Graph[G, VertexStyle -> Table[i -> chi[0, i], {i, 1, n}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The coloring at step `k` will be denoted `chi[k,i]`, where `i` indicates a vertex. I am going to start now assuming that some graph object `G` is given, but that it is not necessarily of the above form, so the vertex `i` might not be an integer:

```
VX = VertexList[G];
n = Length[VX];
EX = EdgeList[G];
m = Length[EX];
```

Obviously if you generate `G` as above, some of that is unnecessary.

Since the underlying graph is static, it's easiest to just hash out the neighborhoods of each vertex quickly:

```
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 NBHD[i] = Select[EX, #[[1]] == i || #[[2]] == i &];
 NBHD[i] = Complement[Union @@ (List @@ # & /@ NBHD[i]), {i}];
 ]
```

From there, we can define `kmax` steps of this process as:

```
kmax = 10;
For[k = 1, k <= kmax, k++,
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    COL = Commonest[chi[k - 1, #] & /@ NBHD[VX[[i]]]];
    chi[k, i] =
     Which[
      Length[COL] == 1, COL[[1]],
      MemberQ[COL, chi[k - 1, i]], chi[k - 1, i],
      True, COL[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[COL]}]]]
      ];
    ];
  ];
```

I've made the choice that if there is a tie among neighbors, if that tie includes the current color, the vertex says the same color. If some vertex has a tie among neighbors that does not include its current color, it changes randomly to one of those most popular colors. (That's what's happening in the `Which` conditional.)

You can display the results with:

```
Manipulate[
 Graph[G, VertexStyle -> Table[i -> chi[k, i], {i, 1, n}]],
 {k, 0, kmax, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm sure there are other/different/better ways to do parts of this, but I think this gets you going the way you want. I hope it is also flexible enough if your `G` has a non-integer vertex set or some other issue. And so long as you define `chi[0,i]` for all `i` using some valid color, you get what you need out. This should be fairly flexible in such regards.

You can reproduce the "usual" automata using `GridGraph` like this:

```
G = GridGraph[{10, 10}];
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  chi[0, i] = {Red, Blue}[[Mod[i, 2] + 1]]
  ];
```

I've used this particular coloring (not random) to get some interesting behavior out of the automaton.

**Update**

To achieve the tie-breaking rule where ties result in no color change, just swap out:

```
     If[
      Length[COL] == 1, COL[[1]], chi[k - 1, i]
      ];
```

for the `Which` conditional above. Note that this will produce possibly counter-intuitive behavior, like a green node with 10 red neighbors and 10 blue neighbors remaining green without any green neighbors.

Comment: I think there is an error somewhere. 
Initial graph: http://i.imgur.com/M7e8D4k.jpg
After one iteration: http://i.imgur.com/3vfNnBj.jpg

I'll add an edit to my question for further clarification, but when applying the rule, the new graph should look like what would happen if we updated every vertex at the same time (synchronous updating) instead of one, then another (sequential updating), since vertex colors could change based in intermediate updates. I'll add further clarification to the majority rule. We should only consider a vertex itself when updating in the event of a tie.

Comment: "We should only consider a vertex itself when updating in the event of a tie." I don't understand. That is already addressed in my code and in my commentary. I also cannot reproduce this error you are introducing.

Comment: And thanks Sjoerd for the images, although my mind is having a bit of a paradoxical moment when a static image is used as the output of a random algorithm XD

Comment: No. It doesn't. `chi[k,x]` gives the coloring of vertex `x` at step `k` and this depends only on various values of `chi[k-1,_]`. It also does not include any vertex in its own list of neighbors. That's what `Complement` does.

Comment: I just want to say, it is very disappointing to have the questioner continue to insist this code is "insynchronous" [sic] and includes a vertex in its own neighbors. It has neither problem (and has not been modified), and I think others would appreciate it if the time one spends writing answers for you would be reciprocated by taking the time to read those answers more carefully.

Comment: 1) Your original code was buggy as the images showed (the images in the links above seem to only make sense if the updating rule is both sequential and the vertex itself is included in the neighborhood.

2) I apologize for not completely reconsidering your code. After fiddling with it, I was able to get it to do what I wanted with generalized petersen graphs. It works great. Now I just need to find a way to save output and check for periods. But these seem like projects of their own. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT: When inputting the graph to be Petersen[40,6], the initial coloring doesn't work out and the program has an error. Only some of the vertices are red or blue and the manipulate box won't update any vertices. Also, where specifically in the code is the initial coloring set? I would like to alter this later on so that there are "blue-heavy" and "red-heavy" colorings.

Comment: The line `For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
  chi[0, i] = {Red, Blue}[[RandomInteger[] + 1]]
  ];` constructs a random coloring for `chi[0,i]`. You are probably not coloring all the vertices. You need to update the coloring and so forth accordingly.

Comment: And no one can reproduce the "bug" you indicated. I've tested a few dozen random graphs and I see no "bugs" -- I suspect you are defining the colorings incorrectly, which would of course result in the problems you noted in your imgur links. The only "bug" I can produce is that isolated vertices have empty neighborhoods, which shouldn't occur in the first place. I didn't throw them out, and I'm not going to take the time to whip up a one liner to do that.